# How to change column type while preserving data in .net database project?

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, database-project

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GameDetails]
(
    [GameId] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Minutes] INT NULL,    
    CONSTRAINT [PK_GameDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (GameId)
) WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.GameDetailsHistory));


INSERT INTO GameDetails(Minutes) VALUES(1),(2.1),(3)
```

I want to convert Minutes into nvarchar(30) on GameDetails and my temporal table on my database project

This is my the sql script on my predeployment script

```
--create temp table to temporarily store data
CREATE TABLE #GameDetails (GameId INT, [Minutes] INT NULL)

--insert to temp table
INSERT INTO #GameDetails (Minutes) SELECT [Minutes] FROM [dbo].[GameDetails]
--set minutes to null so i can alter column to nvarchar(30)
UPDATE  [dbo].[GameDetails] SET [Minutes] = NULL

--alter column type
IF EXISTS 
(
SELECT      1
FROM        [information_schema].[columns]
WHERE       [table_name] = 'GameDetails'
AND         [column_name] = 'Minutes'
AND         [data_type] = 'INT'
)
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GameDetails] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GameDetails] ALTER COLUMN [Minutes] NVARCHAR(30)
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GameDetailsHistory] ALTER COLUMN [Minutes] NVARCHAR(30)
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GameDetails] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = [dbo].[GameDetailsHistory]));
END


UPDATE
    [dbo].[GameDetails]
SET
    S.[Minutes] = D.[Minutes]
FROM
    [dbo].[GameDetails] AS S
    INNER JOIN #GameDetails AS D
        ON S.GameId = convert(nvarchar(30), D.GameId)
```

UPDATE
[dbo].[GameDetailsHistory]
SET
S.[Minutes] = D.[Minutes]
FROM
[dbo].[GameDetails] AS S
INNER JOIN #GameDetails AS D
ON S.GameId = convert(nvarchar(30), D.GameId)

Im getting this error

The multi-part identifier "S.Minutes" could not be bound.

Comment: No need to specify table aliases for the target column of the `UPDATE` since the column is always the updated table.  Change to `SET [Minutes] = D.[Minutes]`.

Comment: @Charlieface, the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql) says "If the object being updated is the same as the object in the FROM clause and there is only one reference to the object in the FROM clause, an object alias may or may not be specified". I don't see any evidence of a cross join in the plan, although I personally specify the alias as the target when using the `UPDATE...FROM` syntax.